# Xpath from the following properties

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I want to select the date+time of the following webpage

https://geoinfo.nmt.edu/nmtso/events/home.cfml

And the xpath for the first one is `/html/body/div/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]`
So I would like a xpath for every row, so I can extract it with scrapy. Any way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The xpath would be //table/tbody/tr/td[1] or in
scrapy:

```
daterows = response.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[1]").getall()
```

which should return 123 rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use this xpath to get the date+time value of each row-

```
//tbody//tr/td[1]/text()
```